# How can I properly output the correct double value?

Tags: java, primitive-types

So I'm trying to enhance these types to get output d = 5.5, I tried different types and what I get is 5.0 , what should I do to get correct output?

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 3;
    int e = 2;
    double d = (double)(a) + b/c/e;
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: You can either just use doubles for all your variables or you need to cast your ints to doubles BEFORE you divide (as division with ints will truncate the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you looking for?:

```
double d = (double)(a) + ((double)(b/c))/(e);
```

Comment: You could also do ,double d = a + (b/c/(double)e);

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = a + (double)(e / b);
```

Comment: where is c tell me please?))

Comment: you don't need c for that value.

Comment: then it becomes a math puzzle.  How about a + b - e - (double)(c / e)

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = 5.0;
double b = 4.0;
double c = 4.0;
double  e = 2.0;
double d = a + b/c/e;
System.out.println(d);
```

This will give 5.5 :)

Comment: ah.. I didnt check the actual computation.. just the types :)